# Elements are not loading in MacOS | Selenium

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I have a website that uses a table of rows of data. My app scraps these data, it works fine on windows whether in `headless` or not, but on MacOS in `headless`, it takes very long time to load or it might not even load. Does any one have any idea on how to solve this?

My browser options:

```
expanduser = os.path.expanduser('~')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={expanduser}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\{profile}')
options.add_argument("headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
return browser
```

Comment: this `options.add_argument("headless")` should be `options.add_argument("--headless")`

Comment: hey @cruisepandey, do you have any ideas, 'cause there is no one answering?